# QML WebView, google sign-in button and app authorization

Tags: webview, qml, google-signin

I try to implement authorization via google in my applications but I have one problem.
In normal browser authorization works the next way:

1. Click on google sign-in button
2. Open new page with google authorization
3. Denied/Grant permissions to app
4. Page closed automatically
5. Page with google sign-in button reloaded automatically

But in QML WebView the last 2 steps doesn't work. Does anybody has ideas how I can do this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use [this example](http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/05/oauth2-explained-with-qt-quick/) for `WebView` OAuth2  authentication. Usually Websites use OAuth2 for authentication and authorization. The Example is for Facebook , but it can be applied for Google.

Comment: It is autorization on facebook but not using facebook to authorize third sevice.And one more: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/23/google_to_block_web_views_from_using_its_oauth/